# Woocommerce Get Order Details On Coupon Id (Kloon Client Library)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a use of kloon client API in my php site and adding coupons through it into my word press site , now that if a customer purchase on my word press site giving its information (name , email etc) and providing  a coupon code to get a discount , this information is stored in woocommerce database against an order id. I can get the order details using my kloon client library by providing an order id. but i need to get the order details based on my coupon code. It seems there is no function provided for this purpose, neither in kloon client API not in woocommerce REST API. I need to know if there is any such functionality provided that i can get the order details based on coupon code? if not can i somehow write this on my own. any hints ? ..
Thanks